# List of functions with duplicates

Tags: list, function, scala, concurrency

Suppose I have a list `List[() => Int]` and need to invoke all the functions to get the list of results.

```
def invoke(fs: List[() => Int]): List[Int] = fs map (_())
```

What if `fs` has duplicates ? I can probably memoize the results but I need to invoke these functions concurrently. It looks like I need to do some preprocessing to make sure each function is invoked only once.

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generically, there's no way of knowing whether two functions are equal. Even if you were looking at two copies of the same function instance, they might invoke some side effect (e.g. generating a random number) so it would be incorrect in some sense to elide the second call. In the cases where the function provably doesn't have side effects, the JVM can probably figure that out for itself. So I honestly think you're solving the wrong problem here.

But if you really want to memoize, I'd use scalaz `Memo`. The different kinds of `Memo` document what thread safety guarantees they offer.

```
def execute(fs: List[() => Int]) = {
  val m = Memo.mutableHashMapMemo({f: (() => Int) => f()})
  fs map m
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My actual problem is a bit different. I have a list of requests and perform remote calls with the requests concurrently. I've changed the problem definition for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `Memo` by the way. I will read about it.

Answer (score 0):

May be using `lazy`:

```
def foo1(): Int = { println("f1"); 1 }
def foo2(): Int = { println("f2"); 2 }

def toLazy(f: () => Int): () => Int = {
  lazy val res = f()
  () => res
}

val f1 = toLazy(foo1)
val f2 = toLazy(foo2)

val flist = List(f1, f2, f1)

println("invoking...")
val res = invoke(flist)
println(res)

// invoking...
// f1
// f2
// List(1, 2, 1)
```

If `f1` requests fail and you handle Exception to allow invocation chain to proceed, lazy for `f1` will be initialized by the first successful response for `f1`.